# What is a Surefire way to get a string Word Count in C#

Tags: c#, regex, text-parsing

I am not sure how to go about this. Right now I am counting the spaces to get the word count of my string but if there is a double space the word count will be inaccurate. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate Version of @Martin v. Löwis, which uses a `foreach` and `char.IsWhiteSpace()` which should be more correct when dealing with other cultures.

```
int CountWithForeach(string para)
{
    bool inWord = false;
    int words = 0;
    foreach (char c in para)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            if( inWord )
                words++;
            inWord = false;
            continue;
        }
        inWord = true;
    }
    if( inWord )
        words++;

    return words;
}
```

Comment: How many words is "run-of-the-mill"? (just something to think about)

Comment: @280Z28 - you bring up a good point. fyi even MS Word treats that as 1 word.

Comment: what about "one.two three;four"

Comment: @codeulike Yes another good point. As this was only meant to be an alternate, more culturally aware version of another posters answer, I'll leave it as-is. In a real program I'd have unit tests to indicate exactly what I expected. You could say this is more of an approach to solving the answer for yourself. The benefits, as stated elsewhere, are that it works in a single pass and has minimal memory pressure.

Answer (score 3):

While solutions based on Split are short to write, they might get expensive, as all the string objects need to be created and then thrown away. I would expect that an explicit algorithm such as

```
  static int CountWords(string s)
  {
    int words = 0;
    bool inword = false;
    for(int i=0; i < s.Length; i++) {
      switch(s[i]) {
      case ' ':case '\t':case '\r':case '\n':
          if(inword)words++;
          inword = false;
          break;
      default:
          inword = true;
          break;
      }
    }
    if(inword)words++;
    return words;
  }
```

is more efficient (plus it can also consider additional whitespace characters).

Comment: If you're going that route, I would suggest a while loop, an index variable and string.IndexOfAny(char[], int).

Comment: @bobbymcr I don't see how that would help. Presumably IndexOfAny is just linearly searching.

Comment: On my system, the IndexOfAny approach is indeed faster.  Linear scan + switch = between 0.014 and 0.015 ms; while + IndexOfAny = between 0.011 and 0.012 ms.  Code here: http://pastebin.ca/1551255 This hardly matters, but I wanted to be sure! :)

Comment: Whoops, there was a bug in the previous code... corrected: http://pastebin.ca/1551268.  Perf results are the same.

Comment: @bobbymcr: I can't reproduce your results. The case version runs 0.008ms, the indexof version 0.016ms, using VS 2008. If I make the string much longer (e.g. doubling it 10 times), the indexof version consistently takes twice as long.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
var input = "This is a  test";
var count = input.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

Comment: Splitting has a huge overhead associated with it. A loop through the characters will be the fastest path. OTOH, RegEx will likely be slower than Split since the resulting array is of a less complex type (string) than a Match object will be.

Comment: I call bullsh*t on richard's statement, turns out split is actually faster in some cases and only marginally slower than the foreach solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx):

```
string sentence = "This     is a sentence     with  some spaces.";
string[] words = sentence.Split(new char[] { ' ' },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int wordCount = words.Length;
```